# Javascript : resquestAnimationFrame as object property

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

In my javascript code, I create a foo object.

I create a draw() method.

In my foo object, window.requestAnimationFrame() is a value of a foo property called foo.requestAnimationFrame.

But when I call foo.requestAnimationFrame(foo.draw) to execute foo.draw again, it doesn't work because console javascript in chrome displays this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Here my javascript code :

```
var foo = {

   "init" : function()
    {
        foo.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame();

        //Draw : 
        foo.draw();
    }, 

    "draw" : function()
    {
        console.log("Drawing");

        foo.requestAnimationFrame(foo.draw);
    }
};

foo.init();
```

So Why it doesn't work ? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is it that you intend to solve with that? Why not just use `window.requestAnimationFrame()` directly?

Comment: Because I want encapsulate all

Comment: @totoaussi: Assigning it to a property on `foo` doesn't increase encapsulation in any meaningful way.

Comment: @ JonasW - I read right past those `()`, you're right. I leave it to you... :-)

Comment: `console.log(foo.requestAnimationFrame)` and you will see that it is `undefined` as `requestAnimationFrame()` returns nothing.

Comment: @t.j. isnt there a good dupe for this? There must be one ...

Comment: @JonasW.: Quite true!

Comment: @totoaussi: `foo.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame();` => `foo.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;`, see the linked question's answers for why. (But again, I wouldn't do that anyway.)